# Test desktop windows using Selenium WebDriver init on root

Tags: python, selenium

I know that Selenium WebDriver might be mostly for testing web apps but I've seen that there is possibility to handle also desktop windows. I have this piece of code:

```
self._host = "http://localhost:4723"
options = {
    "app": "Root",
    'deviceName': 'WindowsPC',
    'platformName': 'Windows',
}
self.root = webdriver.Remote(self._host, options)
self.root.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Word")
```

And I want to grab here the window with Word document and then edit it. I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 77, in test_python_is_python
    self.root.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Word")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_accessibility_id'
```

Any ideas? Because for me it looks exactly like in example.
Thanks!

Comment: You want WinAppDriver: https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver  Though if all you need is to edit a doc file, com control or POI solutions might be better suited for that.

Comment: Thanks. I found good solution here I think https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1330